# changing one or multiple values at once

Tags: java, string, comparison

I am trying to code a method where i can choose to change the value of the variable "address", and if i do not want to change, i can have the option not to. I'm not sure what is the problem here, thank you very much for the help.

```
public void change(){
    keyboard t = new keyboard();
    String ad;
    System.out.println("If you don't wish to change, just press enter");
    ad = t.readString("Type in the new address: ");
        if (ad != "")
            adress = ad;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing two `String` objects via `!=`. But Strings have to be compared by `.equals`:

```
if (!ad.equals("")) {
    //foo
}
```

See [How do I compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for further information.

Comment: @user3511983 You are very welcome (and welcome to SO as well ;)  ). You can mark this answer as _accepted_ if it satisfied you.